# c++ gui button output

Tags: c++, qt

i have a few questions regarding the gui of cplusplus using Qt creator
well i output an array using a forloop when user's choice is for example "1"

so in qt i created a button for that and i linked it with another window

so when i press on the button it opens another window
now i want to add the output of the forloop into this window
should i include iostream in the new window's .cpp file?
or what should i enter exactly?

in the mainwindow.cpp file here is the code i used to open a new window

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    movies movies;
    movies.setModal(true);
    movies.exec();
}
```

thanks.

Comment: What should your output look like? Is it static text? Is it a multi choice? Is it a graph? Or something else?

Comment: Well its an array of a structure and i output it using forloop @UriBrecher

Comment: And this forloop will do what with the structure? I assume text because you mentioned a ostream right?

Comment: sure i already included a text file where it reads the arrays structure from @UriBrecher

Answer (score 0):

You should add a QTextEdit to your window (can be done via Qdesigner). And give this object a name e.g. Textout. Then in the code you should get a pointer to this object through your ui object. And you can use one of many methods to set the text of this object. setText is one option

```
ui->Textout->setText(Your_output_as_qstring)
```

Your can use QTextStream to format your text if necessary. Formating can be done with QString as well.

Answer (score 0):

example:

```
#include <sstream>

#include <QLabel>
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    for (auto s: {"first line", "second line"})
        ss << s << std::endl;

    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QLabel l;
    l.setText(ss.str().c_str());
    l.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```